# Solr get facets on each root document

Tags: solr, facet, faceted-search

I have a JSON with documents and each document has a few `_childDocuments_` I want to search in the parent and get back the parents and facets on each parent separate

Here is a sample JSON

```json
[{
        "id": 1,
        "productName": "Ford Explorer",
        "_childDocuments_": [{
                "id": 6,
                "color": "blue",
                "price": 1000
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "color": "red",
                "price": 2000
            }
        ]

    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "productName": "Ford F150",
        "_childDocuments_": [{
                "id": 10,
                "color": "blue",
                "price": 5000
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "color": "red",
                "price": 6000
            }
        ]

    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "productName": "Toyota Highlander",
        "_childDocuments_": [{
                "id": 8,
                "color": "green",
                "price": 1200
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "color": "red",
                "price": 2000
            }
        ]

    }
]
```

I want when I search for Ford I should get back all Fords and in each root document get back facets of the children.

Something like this:

```json
[{
        "id": 1,
        "productName": "Ford Explorer",
        "facets": {
            "count": 2,
            "prices": {
                "buckets": [{
                        "val": 2000,
                        "count": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "val": 3000,
                        "count": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        }

    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "productName": "Ford F150",
        "facets": {
            "count": 2,
            "prices": {
                "buckets": [{
                        "val": 5000,
                        "count": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "val": 6000,
                        "count": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

This is what I got so far

```
q={!parent+which=type:parent}&json.facet={  "prices": {
      "type": "range",
      "field": "price",
      "start": 1000,
      "end": 1000,
      "gap": 1000
    }
    ,   
}
```

But this is only returning facets on all child documents.

Thanks in advance